# Unable to restart Shibboleth service

Tags: shibboleth

I've installed the Shibboleth application (2.5.6.0 for win64) on my server, changing the settings in the shibboleth2.xml file as instructed, but when I go to restart the Shibboleth 2 Daemon service, it won't start after stopping, and I get the following error message -

> The Shibboleth 2 Daemon (Default) service on Local Computer started
> and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in
> use by other sevices or programs.

Sometimes if I restart the server, the service will start back up, but if I try to restart, I run into the same issue.

Also, I'm unable to access the 3 pages that we're instructed to go to:
https://localhost.Shibboleth.sso/Status

[https:///Shibboleth.sso/Session](https://%3Cyour%20server%20URL%3E/Shibboleth.sso/Session)

[https:///Shibboleth.sso/Metadata](https://%3Clocalhost%3E/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata)

But localhost is up and running, and ssl comes up for the site without any certificate errors.

Anyone have any suggestions? We're stumped!

Answer (score 1):

XML error. I didn't close a tag. What worked the fastest to debug, was running it through XML Notepad, which gave the exact line number with the error. I opened it up in my text editor after that, made the changes, double-checked if I could open in XML Notepad, and then attempted to start the Shibb service, and it worked!